# Email gets send from own email address

Tags: php, email

I'd like to begin with saying that I know next to nothing about PHP, I have an email template from a long time ago, and I think I messed something up. 
When I receive an email it says it's from info@ruudbloemhof.nl, which is my own email. As you'll understand, this is rather inconvenient as I can't reply to someone if I don't know their email address. I think I found the piece of code where it all goed wrong, yet I don't know how to fix it.

In the code I see it says that the email is from my own address, I think this is the problem, but as I said, I don't know what to replace it with.

```
private function sendEmail(){
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'To: Ruud <info@ruudbloemhof.nl>' . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= 'From: Ruud <info@ruudbloemhof.nl>' . "\r\n"; 

    $mail = mail($this->email_admin, $this->subject, $this->message, $headers); 

    //$mail = mail($this->email_admin, $this->subject, $this->message,
//       "From: ".$this->name." <".$this->email.">\r\n"
//      ."Reply-To: ".$this->email."\r\n"
//  ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

    if($mail)
    {
        $this->response_status = 1;
        $this->response_html = '<p>Thank You!</p>';
    }
}
```

This is the first part of the code where (I think) is the rest of the information you'll need for a solution:

```
    function __construct($details, $email_admin, $message_min_length){

    $this->name = stripslashes($details['name']);
    $this->email = trim($details['email']);
    $this->subject = 'Contact from Your Website'; // Subject 
    $this->message = stripslashes($details['message']);

    $this->email_admin = $email_admin;
    $this->message_min_length = $message_min_length;

    $this->response_status = 1;
    $this->response_html = '';
}
```

To see everything live the website can be seen [here](http://www.ruudbloemhof.nl)

If you need further information, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Ruud

Comment: `$headers .= 'From: Ruud <info@ruudbloemhof.nl>' . "\r\n";` it does what you tell it to do

Comment: Thanks, I know that, but I want it to say where the email is actually from. And as I said, I don't know how to change it, since I don't know any php.

Comment: The trouble with php is that it all executes before the rest of the page, hence the name, so it would be difficult to actually send an email in this way using it (without a pre-specified address), you could put the address in a POST to a second page that uses a GET to get it, then put that in your $headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set it in your message headers:

`$headers .= 'From: Ruud <info@ruudbloemhof.nl>' . "\r\n";`

Simply replace this way:

`$headers .= 'From: ' . $this->name . '<' . $this->email . '>' . "\r\n";`

You've got similar code commented below:

`"From: ".$this->name." <".$this->email.">\r\n"`